# PSR4 not working?

Tags: php

Class not found, apparently. I've tried various things but nothing works.

Composer:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "application/"
    }
}
```

File structure:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/LsyaR.png

```
<?php

namespace App\Library\Classes;

defined('START') or exit('We couldn\'t process your request right now.');

class Application
{
    private static $libraries = array();

    public static function get($library) {
        if (isset(self::$libraries[$library]) && isset(self::$classes[$library])) {
            return self::$libraries[$library];
        }

        $fixedLibrary = str_replace('.', '/', $library);
        $file = ROOT . '/application/library/classes/' . strtolower($fixedLibrary) . '.php';

        self::$libraries[$library] = $library;

        $declared = get_declared_classes();
        $workingClass = end($declared);

        self::$libraries[$library] = new $workingClass();

        return self::$libraries[$library];
    }
}

?>
```

Error is on this line:

```
Application::get('test')->test();
```

Yet, if I change it to this, it works:

```
include ROOT . '/application/Library/Application.php';
App\Library\Classes\Application::get('test')->test();
```

Comment: Please, provide the error message.

Comment: Do you include in your code composer generated autoload.php?

Comment: Where is your 'vendor' folder with 'composer' and autoload.php? Don't see it in your file structure? And you don't seem to have: `require 'vendor/autoload.php';`

Comment: Don't post images when you can write the information as text.

Comment: I never included the full class @jibsteroos, vendor is removed from my IDE as its irrelevant. I do include the autoload.

Comment: @Timurib `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Application' not found in C:\Users\admin\Desktop\glo-cms\application\bootstrap.php:11`

Comment: have you tried to re-run dump-autoload to re-generate the vendor/autoload.php file?

Comment: Just checked; autoload.php requires 'composer/autoload_real.php', which in turn requires(amongst other things) 'autoload_psr4.php'... you might want to try with the whole composer folder.

Comment: When debugging, always change *one thing at a time*: in your example, you've changed *both* which files you include, *and* how you write the class name (`Application::get` vs `App\Library\Classes\Application::get`).

Answer (score 1):

The [PSR4](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) is not built-in part or PHP, you need an implementation of autoloader to use this standard such as provided by the Composer.

When you install or update depedencies, composer generates the relevant code of autoloading, but you can directly update it by the command [`dump-autoload`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#dump-autoload-dumpautoload-), as @jibsteroos said. Next you should explicitly include the file `vendor/autoload.php` in the entry point of your application.

Also, error message says about class `Application`, but you should add the `use` statement at first:

```
use App\Library\Classes\Application;

Application::get('test')->test();
```

Or use the fully qualified class name (class name with namespace prefix):

```
\App\Library\Classes\Application::get('test')->test();
```